# Performance & Learning differences between ArrayList constructors

Tags: java

Are there any actual performance or bad/good practice differences between the following?

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>()
{{
    add( "ohai" );
    add( "Hey;)" );
    add( "Hii" );
}};
// or..
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String> ( Arrays.asList( "ohai" , "Hey;)" , "Hii" ) );
// or..
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>()
{{
    addAll( Arrays.asList( "ohai" , "Hey;)" , "Hii" );
}};
// or finally..
List<String> l = Arrays.asList( "ohai" , "Hey;)" , "Hii" );
```

Comment: I would use the one which you find simplest and clearest.  There is lots more ways of doing this with increasing complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double brace initialization versions will be similar speed, and will also be the slowest. This is because it creates an anonymous class to run the inner block during initialization. Double brace initialization can be syntactically nice, and if you only need to create the List once, the performance decrease is negligible. If you're creating hundreds of lists you might want to choose a different method.

Using `addAll` vs `add` you will probably not see a performance difference.

Writing `new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(...))` creates a copy of the list returned by `Arrays.asList`, which will be slower than just calling `Arrays.asList`.

Wrapping the list in an `ArrayList` is good idea depending on the operations being performed. For example; `ArrayList` very good for doing index based lookups.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind when programming. Thanks a lot, and marked as best answer. Keep on going like you do ;)